# Why does item disappear when anchors changed?

Tags: qt, qml

Here is a Tab in a TabView in my qml file:

```
    Tab {
            title: "Lab"
            Rectangle {
                width: 300
                height: 600
                anchors.margins: 60
                color: "gray"
//                anchors.top: parent.top
//                anchors.bottom: parent.verticalCenter
//                anchors.margins: 10
                Column {
                    id : buttons
//                                    anchors.top: parent.top
//                                    anchors.bottom: parent.verticalCenter
                    anchors.fill: parent
                                    anchors.margins: 10
                    spacing: 2

                    Repeater {
                        model: ["Add entity", "Add Unique Comp", "Add light", "Add Prefab", "Add entity to prefab", "None"]

                        Rectangle {
                            width: parent.width - 20
                            height: 24
                            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter

                            radius: 3

                            color: "lightBlue"

                            Button {
                                width: parent.width * 0.5
                                height: parent.height * 0.8
                                anchors.left: parent.left
                                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                                text: index +": "+modelData
                                onClicked: {
                                    console.log("clicked ", modelData);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Here a TabView is used, above is one of the tabs. `x y` are not specified.

If I remove `anchors.fill: parent`, the `Rectangle` will disappear on the screen. Why did this happen? Or how could I debug this?

Comment: To which rectangle do you mean? If you refer to the second rectangle it is obvious, Column has size 0, 0 it will only change if you put it explicitly or use the anchors.

Comment: @eyllanesc Yes! Got it! So `anchors.top: parent.top anchors.bottom: parent.verticalCenter` can only specify the height of `Column`, the width is still 0.